# creating refs in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

my question is will `this.myRef.current` refer to the **actual DOM node** or to the react virtual DOM's node?

Comment: actual DOM node - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html you can use JS DOM api and test to verify `this.myRef.current.innerText="some text"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488816/in-react-do-refs-reference-the-virtual-dom-or-the-actual-dom

Comment: Good find, @Justcode!

Comment: @Kunukn Is it anything different from this? "When the ref attribute is used on a custom class component, the ref object receives the mounted instance of the component as its current" as quoted in docs

Comment: @ClaxX the ref is actual DOM, you can try to insert this in your code example `componentDidMount(){console.log(this.myRef.current)}`  It will print the DOM node or try with this code `componentDidMount(){this.myRef.current.innerText = "DOM node"}`